# Removing a node from a linked list (stack)

Tags: python, linked-list, stack

I have to write a linked list in for of a stack, that means I just can delete numbers on the very top and push a number from the top of the stack. Unfortunately my pop() func is not working, i hope you can help me:

```
# ---------------init--------------
class node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None # contains the data
        self.next = None # contains the reference to the next node


class linked_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cur_node = None

# ---------------is_empty--------------
    def is_empty(self):
    if self.cur_node == None:
        print ("list is empty")
    else:
        print ("List = ")
        ll.list_print()

# ---------------is_full--------------

# ---------------push--------------

    def push(self, data):
        new_node = node() # create a new node
        new_node.data = data
        new_node.next = self.cur_node # link the new node to the 'previous' node.
        self.cur_node = new_node #  set the current node to the new one.

# ---------------pop--------------

    def pop(self):
    print(node)
    node = self.cur_node
    while node:
        if node.next == None:
        node = None
        break 
        else:
        node=node.next


# ---------------print--------------
    def list_print(self):
        ...


ll = linked_list()

ll.is_empty()
ll.push(1)
ll.push(3)
ll.push(2)
ll.is_empty()
ll.pop()
ll.list_print()
```

Current output before pop() is

```
2
3
1
```

After pop() it should be

```
3
1
```

Comment: I have no idea of python, but apparently in your `pop` you don't change `self.cur_node`, but just follow the stack to the bottom. What about just using `self.cur_node = self.cur_node.next`?

Comment: @Codor my prof gave me the exercise to write a function is_full(). In my opinion it is not possible to finde a full linked list, because you can always create a "new node". I guess, it's a fault of him... what do  you think?

Comment: @Codor That's correct, it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently iterates through the stack and doesn't modify anything.

Think about the state of the stack when the function is called.  In your example, it's like this:

[image: stack before pop]

After calling `pop()`, you want it to be like this:

[image: stack after pop]

So all you need to do is set `self.cur_node` to `self.cur_node.next`.  You don't have to do anything to delete the node containing `2`, Python will do this automatically once it is no longer being referenced.

Answer (score 0):

pop function may be this could help you

```
 def pop(self, i):
        '''(LinkedList, int) -> NoneType
        Remove and return item at index. Raise IndexError if list is empty or
        index is out of range.'''

        if i < 0 or i >= self.num_elements:
            raise IndexError("pop index out of range")
        if i == 0:
            result = self.front.key
            self.front = self.front.next
        else:
            node = self.front
            for j in range(i - 1):
                node = node.next
            result = node.next.key
            node.next = node.next.next
        self.num_elements -= 1
        return result
```

Comment: with this func you can search for a number and delete it, but i have to delete the very last element without telling the compiler to delete a special number on a special position

Comment: def PopNode( self, index ):
        prev = None
        node = self.head
        i = 0

        while ( node != None ) and ( i < index ):
            prev = node
            node = node.next
            i += 1

        if prev == None:
            self.head = node.next
        else:
            prev.next = node.next

Comment: Doing the OP's assignment for him isn't going to help him, plus this implementation has a different signature than the original code and doesn't even work (it expects nodes to have a `key` attribute, which they don't).

Comment: @augurar maybe you have a solution for me??

Comment: @WirJun See [Codor's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27868366/removing-a-node-from-a-linked-list-stack/27868455?noredirect=1#comment44139322_27868366), above.